# How to use multiple locations' data from for loop as leaflet markers to use in click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, for-loop, leaflet

I have a leaflet map that has markers showing the top cities in a chosen country.

`locationList` is an array of objects, each one containing info per city (lat, lng, cityName). These values are being used to add markers onto the map, and are also stringified for use in a PHP call to a weather API cURL routine.

I've added popups displaying each city name onto the map successfully through a for loop, however I would like to be able to add functionality to each marker so that when you click on any `$cityMarker` the weather data for that particular location pops up in a modal (after AJAX call).

At the moment this is only working for the final object in the locationList array, as the click event and subsequent AJAX call is only being fired from the last item of the loop before the click event handler.

Is there an easy way to get around this so that the click event fires for all locations, depending on which one is clicked? I can't figure out how to get all data out of the loop to use individually in $cityMarker.

Thank you !

```
                    var locationList = [];
                    citiesArray.forEach(city => {
                        locationList.push({
                            lat: city.lat,
                            lng: city.lng,
                            cityName: city.toponymName
                        });
                    });
                    
                    console.log(locationList)
                    for (var i=0; i < locationList.length; i++) {
                        console.log(locationList[i])
                        $cityMarker = L.marker(new L.latLng([locationList[i]['lat'], locationList[i]['lng']]))
                        .addTo($layers)
                        .bindPopup('Name: ' + locationList[i]['cityName'])
                    }
                
                        $($cityMarker).on('click', () => {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "getInfo.php",
                                type: 'POST',
                                data: {
                                    locationList: JSON.stringify(locationList)
                                },
                                success: function(result) {
                    
                                    console.log(result);

                                    for (let i=0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
                                        $('.modal').modal('show');
                                        $('#openWeatherResult').html(result['data'][i]['openWeather']['weather'][0]['description'])
                                    }                                       

                                },
                                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                    console.log(errorThrown);
                                    console.log(textStatus);
                                    console.log(jqXHR);
                                }
                            });
                        });
```

PHP:

```
<?php


    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $executionStartTime = microtime(true) / 1000;
    
    $locationList = json_decode($_POST['locationList'], true);

    $locationArray = [];
    
    foreach ($locationList as $location){
        $data['lat'] = $location['lat'];
        $data['lng'] = $location['lng'];
        array_push($locationArray, $data);
    }

    // openweather routine

    foreach ($locationArray as $location){
        $lat = $location['lat'];
        $lng = $location['lng'];
    
        $openWeatherUrl='api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' . $lat . '&lon='  . $lng  . '&units=metric&appid=demo';
    
        $openWeatherch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($openWeatherch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($openWeatherch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($openWeatherch, CURLOPT_URL,$openWeatherUrl);
    
        $openWeatherResult = curl_exec($openWeatherch);
    
        curl_close($openWeatherch);
    
        $openWeather = json_decode($openWeatherResult, true);
    
        $output['data'][] = ['location' => $location, 'openWeather' => $openWeather];
    }
    
    $output['status']['code'] = "200";
    $output['status']['name'] = "ok";
    $output['status']['description'] = "mission saved";
    $output['status']['returnedIn'] = (microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) / 1000 . " ms";
    
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    
    echo json_encode($output);

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `click` listener in the loop:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < locationList.length; i++) {
    console.log(locationList[i])
    const $cityMarker = L.marker(new L.latLng([locationList[i]['lat'], locationList[i]['lng']]))
        .addTo($layers)
        .bindPopup('Name: ' + locationList[i]['cityName'])

    $($cityMarker).on('click', () => {
        $.ajax({
            url: "getInfo.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                locationList: JSON.stringify(locationList)
            },
            success: function(result) {

                console.log(result);

                for (let i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
                    $('.modal').modal('show');
                    $('#openWeatherResult').html(result['data'][i]['openWeather']['weather'][0]['description'])
                }

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(errorThrown);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(jqXHR);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

**Edit**
Your problem is that you always load all weather data and the loop through the data. In the next step you change the html / text of `$('#openWeatherResult')`, but it can't have multiple htmls / texts so it always overwrides the text before ... so it will always display the last entry of the loop.

I suggest you to overwrite / create new php file for loading the data of a single entry: `getSingleInfo.php`

```
<?php


    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $executionStartTime = microtime(true) / 1000;
    
  
        $lat = $_POST['lat'];
        $lng = $_POST['lng'];
    
        $openWeatherUrl='api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' . $lat . '&lon='  . $lng  . '&units=metric&appid=demo';
    
        $openWeatherch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($openWeatherch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($openWeatherch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($openWeatherch, CURLOPT_URL,$openWeatherUrl);
    
        $openWeatherResult = curl_exec($openWeatherch);
    
        curl_close($openWeatherch);
    
        $openWeather = json_decode($openWeatherResult, true);
    
        $output['data'][] = ['location' => $location, 'openWeather' => $openWeather];
    
    
    $output['status']['code'] = "200";
    $output['status']['name'] = "ok";
    $output['status']['description'] = "mission saved";
    $output['status']['returnedIn'] = (microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) / 1000 . " ms";
    
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    
    echo json_encode($output);

?>
```

And then change your ajax call to:

```
$($cityMarker).on('click', (e) => {
        var marker = e.target;
        $.ajax({
            url: "getSingleInfo.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                lat: marker.getLatLng().lat,
                lng: marker.getLatLng().lng,
            },
            success: function(result) {
```

Comment: Edit - thanks for your response! I've moved the click listener into the loop as suggested and the modal is now appearing for whatever marker I click. However, every modal is still only displaying the weather for the last item in the array - this data is being shown through `$('#openWeatherResult').html(result['data'][i]['openWeather']['weather'][0]['description']` Please see edit in original post for the PHP file that - to get marker data I decode locationList and use each location's lat/lng to call a weather API. Hope that makes sense. Thanks again